# s3 file to local system php

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, php-5.3

how would I get the file from amazon s3 to local system using php.

I am trying to do this but its not working

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3("key 1", " acces pass");
        $s3->getObject("Bucket/filename");
//write to local
        $fp = fopen('/tmp/filename.mp4', 'w');
        fpassthru($fp);
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to save the file to my local server from s3

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: it doesnt pull the file from s3 and save on my server

Comment: What's the AmazonS3 class you're using? I use http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class but I've never tried to download a file like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs for [`getObject`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object):

You need to either pass the remote file name as the 2nd param, then in the options set the value of 'fileDownload' to a file name or an OPEN file resource as a parameter there.

Example:

```
$s3->getObject('myBucket','myRemoteFile', array('fileDownload' => 'localFileName'));
```

Answer (score 6):

As of 3.35.x verison AWS SDK -- the following snippet works with `SaveAs`. 
Notice the buket name, key, and saveas with full path with file name.

```
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'SaveAs' => $path . $model->file_name,
));
```